# Unable to show files on mounted SAN storage

Tags: local-storage, ubuntu-16.04, san

Unable to share file using SAN storage.I have SAN storage and attached it to 4 servers.After creating a file on server1,it doesnt showing on server2.It shows only after unmounting and mounting the SAN again on that server.How can i resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "issue" is in the file systems. On each of the servers, your filesystem supposes it has exclusive rights on that volume. What's you need is a cluster-file system that it aware of some other host can change the data on the disk.

Comment: ,My host machines are xfs file system and SAN file system is ext4.CAn you explain it more detaily?

Comment: You must replace ext4 filesystem on the shared block-device with a cluster filesystem. Look here and make a choice according to your needs, restrictions and abilities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_file_system